# CSS not applying

Tags: jquery, css

Okay so on my homepage `http://www.stat-me.com` i have a link that when pressed activates some jquery.

I have css on it saying `margin-bottom:517px;`  yet it does not affect it

It is the link with the text `XXXXXXXXXXXX`   and if you go to the actual page you will see that it sticks to the bottom left corner under the transparent bar down there

Sorry but because i am a new user i cant post the code because it has hyperlinks in it but you can go to the link above and click view source and you will see it.

Basicly if you click news feed it appears that is what i want to happen to the login script once clicked on the `XXXXXXXXX` link

```
<?php
session_start();

if (isset($_SESSION['id'])){
    header ('Location: dock.php');
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Stat - Me</title>
<link href="style/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link rel="icon" href="http://www.stat-me.com/images/sm_shortcut.jpg" type="image/x-icon" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://www.stat-me.com/images/sm_shortcut.jpg" type="image/x-icon" />


<script src="js/jquery/jquery-1.4.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
// run the function below once the DOM(Document Object Model) is ready
$(document).ready(function() {
    // trigger the function when clicking on an assigned element
    $(".toggle").click(function () {
        // check the visibility of the next element in the DOM
        if ($(this).next().is(":hidden")) {
            $(this).next().show(); // slide it down
        } else {
            $(this).next().hide(); // hide it
        }
    });
});
</script>


<style type="text/css">
<!--


a:link    {
  /* Applies to all unvisited links */
  text-decoration:  none;
  color:            #F00;
  } 

a:visited {
  /* Applies to all visited links */
  text-decoration:  none;
  color:            #F00;
  } 
a:hover   {
  /* Applies to links under the pointer */
  text-decoration:  underline;
  color:            #F00;
  } 
a:active  {
    /* Applies to activated links */
  text-decoration:  underline;
    color:            #282828;
  }
img{
    border-style:none;
}

.topbar {
    background-color: #282828;
    height: 45px;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
}

.bottombar {
    background-color: #282828;
    height: 45px;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    filter:alpha(opacity=85);
    -moz-opacity:0.85;
    -khtml-opacity: 0.85;
    opacity: 0.85;
    /*margin-bottom:5px; */
    z-index:444;
   /*padding-bottom: 20px;*/
}
.login {
    color: #F00;
    text-align:center;
}

.hiddenDiv{
    display:none;
    height: 22.5px;
    width: auto;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 44px;
    filter:alpha(opacity=85);
    -moz-opacity:0.85;
    -khtml-opacity: 0.85;
    opacity: 0.85;
    z-index:444;
}

#news_feed_img{
    height: 25px;
    width: auto;
    position: fixed;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 47px;
    filter:alpha(opacity=85);
    -moz-opacity:0.85;
    -khtml-opacity: 0.85;
    opacity: 0.85;
    /*margin-bottom:5px; */
    z-index:444;
   /*padding-bottom: 20px;*/
}


/* BELOW CSS BELONGS TO LOG IN JQ */
.secondehiddendiv{
    display:none;
    margin-top:40px;
    margin-left:480px;
}

.chat-bubble {
  background-color:#242424;
  border:2px solid #F00;
  line-height:1.3em;
  margin:10px auto;
  padding:10px;
  position:relative;
  text-align:center;
  width:217px;
  -moz-border-radius:10px;
  -webkit-border-radius:10px;
  -moz-box-shadow:0 0 5px #888888;
  -webkit-box-shadow:0 0 5px #888888;
}

.chat-bubble-arrow-border {
  border-color: transparent transparent #F00 transparent;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 10px;
  height:0;
  width:0;
  position:absolute;
  bottom:163px;
  left:179px;
}

.chat-bubble-arrow {
  border-color: transparent transparent #242424 transparent;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 10px;
  height:0;
  width:0;
  position:absolute;
  bottom:160px;
  left:179px;
}

.log_in_img{
    margin-left:117px;
}

/*END OF LOG IN CSS*/

-->
</style>
</head>

<body bgcolor="#FF8C8C">
<div class="topbar">
  <table width="100%">
    <tr>
    <td width="50%">
<a href="http://www.stat-me.com/"><img src="http://www.stat-me.com/images/logo_bar.png" alt="Stat-Me.com" width="202" height="45" /></a>
</td>
    <td width="19%">&nbsp;</td>


    <td width="11%" class="login"><a href="#">LOG IN</a></td>





    <td width="20%"><table align="right" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5">
      <tr>
        <form action="http://www.stat-me.com/member_search.php" method="post" name="main-search" id="main-search">
          <td><input name="searchb" type="hidden" value="true" />
            <input type="text" name="search" size="22" value="" /></td>
          <td><input type="image" src="http://www.stat-me.com/images/search_mag.png" alt="search" /></td>
        </form>
      </tr>
    </table></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>


<div align="center">
<img src="images/INDEX-QUESTIONARE.png" border="0" align="middle" usemap="#Map" />
<map name="Map" id="Map">
  <area shape="rect" coords="23,143,385,384" href="fregister.php" alt="click here to register" />
  <area shape="rect" coords="432,142,781,391" href="fabout.php" alt="What is stat me . com" />
</map>
</div>
<div class="bottombar">
<div align="center" style="color:#F00"><p>      
      &copy; Stat-Me.com Copyright 2010. All Rights Reserverd.
</p></div>    

</div>

<span class="toggle" style="display:block; margin-bottom:517px;">

<a href="#">xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</a>

</span>

<div class="secondehiddendiv">
<div class="chat-bubble">
  <h1 style="color:#F00">LOG IN!</h1>
<form name="login" method="post" action="scripts/login_parse.php">
  <table style="margin-left:-5px; text-align:right; color:#F00;">
    <tr>
        <td>Email:</td>
        <td><input name="email" type="text" size="17" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Password:</td>
        <td><input name="pword" type="text" size="17" /></td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <div class="log_in_img">
  <input type="image" src="http://www.stat-me.com/images/log_in_jq.png" alt="LOG IN"  />
  </div>
</form>

  <div class="chat-bubble-arrow-border"></div>
  <div class="chat-bubble-arrow"></div>

</div>
</div>




<span class="toggle" style="margin-left:40%; margin-bottom:30%;">
<div id="news_feed_img">
<a href="#" style="cursor:pointer;">
<img src="http://www.stat-me.com/images/bar_news_feed.png" alt="News Feed" width="98" />
</a>
</div>




</span>
<div class="hiddenDiv" style="border-top:#F00 3px solid; border-left:#F00 3px solid; border-right:#F00 3px solid; border-bottom:#F00 3px solid; background-color:#484848; width:92.2%;">

<table width="90%">
  <tr>
    <td>
        <marquee scrolldelay="157"><font color="#FF0000"><b>June 21 - 12:00 AM - PM Messaging Re-Enabled!   ...June 17 - 12:00 AM - New LOOK !!!!   ...April 21 - 12:00 AM -  FRIENDS FUNCTIONALITY WORKING !&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;...April 21 - 12:00 AM -  PM MESSAGING NOW AVALIBLE !&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</b></font></marquee>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can post the code if you format it as code using the 101010 button. Then it should be accepted, URLs and all.

Comment: still wont let me it says
Oops! Your edit couldn't be submitted because:

    * we're sorry, but as a spam prevention mechanism, new users can only post a maximum of one hyperlink. Earn 10 reputation to post more hyperlinks.
    * we're sorry, but as a spam prevention mechanism, new users aren't allowed to post images. Earn 10 reputation to post images.

Comment: You now have your 10 points. But if you just indented the code at least 4 spaces (or select it and click the 101010 button), the code would be formatted and SO would accept it.

Comment: I MEAN I GOT IT TO POST CODE NOT THE CSS LOL

Comment: @Matthew: Please cut off the caps, kid :)

Comment: Never mind i  got it lol  had to add display:block to the main span (i.e. span{display:block;} ) i was putting it in the same line lol
thanks everybody

Comment: Since when is "lol" a new form of sentence punctuation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<span> tags are inline elements. For a margin to be applied to it, you also need `display: block;`

Comment: okay so i did 
<span class="toggle" style="display:block; margin-bottom:517px;">
<a href="#">xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</a></span>
and it still doesnt work

Answer (score 1):

The thing is that the element that has a margin of 517px is in fact a span. That means it's an **inline** element. If you replace the `span` tags for `div` tags then the margin works, pushing the bottom downwards or give the span a `display:block` property in the css, meaning it will now be affected by the margin. Inline means if doesn't have structural properties by itself, it will just sit inside it's parent container.

Not sure if that's what you wanted, in case you want it though. But give it a try.

Comment: okay so i did <span class="toggle" style="display:block; margin-bottom:517px;"> <a href="#">xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</a></span> and it still doesnt work

Comment: Try the other solution I gave you. Replace the span with a div element. That should work..

Answer (score 0):

Try `display:block;` on the span.

Comment: okay so i did <span class="toggle" style="display:block; margin-bottom:517px;"> <a href="#">xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</a></span> and it still doesnt work